# How to read content of an RPM in java

Tags: java, rpm

I'm looking for a way to read an RPM's content in java runtime.

Someone has suggested using 7zip to unpack and/or extract the RPM in runtime, using system command for 7zip.

that solution has two cons:

1. It is platform dependent (since the commands will be specific to one OS)
2. It involved third party software.

any ideas?

**EDIT :**
I'm trying to go down Robert's road. Here is my code:

```
String file = "MyRpm.rpm";

CpioArchiveInputStream cpioIn = 
       new CpioArchiveInputStream( new FileInputStream(new File(file)) );
 CpioArchiveEntry cpioEntry;



while ((cpioEntry = cpioIn.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(cpioEntry.getName());
    int tmp;
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    while ((tmp = cpioIn.read()) != -1)
    {
        buf.append((char) tmp);
    }
    System.out.println(buf.toString());
}
cpioIn.close();
```

I'm getting an exception: `java.io.IOException: Unknown magic [????` (The funny characters are from the original error message).

Comment: What's an RMP? Do you mean an RPM?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `commons-compress` has a [cpio package](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/cpio/package-summary.html) which you might find useful in reading the data from RPM files.

Comment: Not sure why that happens, perhaps you can ask on the library's mailing list of open a bug report. I have not used it, just found it with a google search.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library to decompress LZMA: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html